Need to edit values inside USX (XML) file based on a map
I have a special case, I want to adjust the chapter and verse numbers inside a USX file which is a special format of XML.
Documentation: https://ubsicap.github.io/usx/index.html
Here are the first 2 chapters of the book of Psalms:
<usx version="2.0"><book code="PSA">PSA</book><chapter number="1" style="c"/><para style="s1">Book One</para><para style="s1">The Way of the Righteous and the Wicked</para><para style="p"><verse number="1" style="v"/>Blessed is the man
who walks not in the counsel of the wicked,
nor stands in the way of sinners,
nor sits in the seat of scoffers;</para><para style="p"><verse number="2" style="v"/>but his delight is in the law of the Lord,
and on his law he meditates day and night.</para><para style="p"><verse number="3" style="v"/>He is like a tree
planted by streams of water
that yields its fruit in its season,
and its leaf does not wither.
In all that he does, he prospers.</para><para style="p"><verse number="4" style="v"/>The wicked are not so,
but are like chaff that the wind drives away.</para><para style="p"><verse number="5" style="v"/>Therefore the wicked will not stand in the judgment,
nor sinners in the congregation of the righteous;</para><para style="p"><verse number="6" style="v"/>for the Lord knows the way of the righteous,
but the way of the wicked will perish.</para><chapter number="2" style="c"/><para style="s1">The Reign of the Lord’s Anointed</para><para style="p"><verse number="1" style="v"/>Why do the nations rage
and the peoples plot in vain?</para><para style="p"><verse number="2" style="v"/>The kings of the earth set themselves,
and the rulers take counsel together,
against the Lord and against his Anointed, saying,</para><para style="p"><verse number="3" style="v"/>“Let us burst their bonds apart
and cast away their cords from us.”</para><para style="p"><verse number="4" style="v"/>He who sits in the heavens laughs;
the Lord holds them in derision.</para><para style="p"><verse number="5" style="v"/>Then he will speak to them in his wrath,
and terrify them in his fury, saying,</para><para style="p"><verse number="6" style="v"/>“As for me, I have set my King
on Zion, my holy hill.”</para><para style="p"><verse number="7" style="v"/>I will tell of the decree:
The Lord said to me, “You are my Son;
today I have begotten you.</para><para style="p"><verse number="8" style="v"/>Ask of me, and I will make the nations your heritage,
and the ends of the earth your possession.</para><para style="p"><verse number="9" style="v"/>You shall break them with a rod of iron
and dash them in pieces like a potter’s vessel.”</para><para style="p"><verse number="10" style="v"/>Now therefore, O kings, be wise;
be warned, O rulers of the earth.</para><para style="p"><verse number="11" style="v"/>Serve the Lord with fear,
and rejoice with trembling.</para><para style="p"><verse number="12" style="v"/>Kiss the Son,
lest he be angry, and you perish in the way,
for his wrath is quickly kindled.
Blessed are all who take refuge in him.</para></usx>

The way I want to adjust the chapter and verse numbering is based on this mapping: 
Note how the chapter and verse numbering does not match throughout. I chose to show the mapping as an image for convenience but I also have it formatted in a Python dictionary like so:
verse_map = {
    'NUM': {
        '12:16': '13:1',
        '13:1-33': '13:+1',
    },
    ...
    'PSA': {
        '1:1-2:12': 'X:X',
        '3:1-9:20': 'X:+1',
        '10:1': '9:22',
        '10:2-18': '9:+21',
    ...


To be clear, the changes that need to be made are in the verse numbers and chapter number. For example, here part of the original:
<chapter number="44" style="c"/><para style="s1">Come to Our Help</para><para style="p"><verse number="1" style="v"/>O God, we have heard with our ears,
our fathers have told us,
what deeds you performed in their days,
in the days of old:</para><para style="p"><verse number="2" style="v"/>you with your own hand drove out the nations,
but them you planted;
you afflicted the peoples,
but them you set free;</para><para style="p"><verse number="3" style="v"/>for not by their own sword did they win the land,
nor did their own arm save them,
but your right hand and your arm,
and the light of your face,
for you delighted in them.</para>

Here is the correctly adjusted version:
<chapter number="43" style="c"/><para style="s1">Come to Our Help</para><para style="p"><verse number="2" style="v"/>O God, we have heard with our ears,
our fathers have told us,
what deeds you performed in their days,
in the days of old:</para><para style="p"><verse number="3" style="v"/>you with your own hand drove out the nations,
but them you planted;
you afflicted the peoples,
but them you set free;</para><para style="p"><verse number="4" style="v"/>for not by their own sword did they win the land,
nor did their own arm save them,
but your right hand and your arm,
and the light of your face,
for you delighted in them.</para>

Why? Here is the mapping for these passages:
'44:1-49:20': '-1:+1'
Here is what I have so far:
for elem in tree.iter():
    # print book code, chapter number and verse number
    if elem.tag == 'book':
        book_code = elem.get('code')
        print(f"book {book_code}")
    elif elem.tag == 'chapter':
        chapter_number = elem.get('number')
        print(f"chapter {chapter_number}")
    elif elem.tag == 'verse':
        verse_number = elem.get('number')
        print(f"verse {verse_number}")

So right now I am just looping through the entire file and pulling out the book name, chapter, and verses.
output is this:
book PSA
chapter 1
verse 1
verse 2
...
chapter 2
verse 1
...

I'm stumped on the rest.

You can find in the documentation, how to set() the attributes in xml. But what’s the logic behind your numbering system is unclear. Your example doesn’t help, because you don’t use your table values.

Here is an example, how you can set the chapter number to a new value:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

xml_= """\
<usx version="2.0">
  <book code="PSA">PSA</book>
  <chapter number="1" style="c" />
  <para style="s1">Book One</para>
  <para style="s1">The Way of the Righteous and the Wicked</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="1" style="v" />Blessed is the man
who walks not in the counsel of the wicked,
nor stands in the way of sinners,
nor sits in the seat of scoffers;</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="2" style="v" />but his delight is in the law of the Lord,
and on his law he meditates day and night.</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="3" style="v" />He is like a tree
planted by streams of water
that yields its fruit in its season,
and its leaf does not wither.
In all that he does, he prospers.</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="4" style="v" />The wicked are not so,
but are like chaff that the wind drives away.</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="5" style="v" />Therefore the wicked will not stand in the judgment,
nor sinners in the congregation of the righteous;</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="6" style="v" />for the Lord knows the way of the righteous,
but the way of the wicked will perish.</para>
  <chapter number="2" style="c" />
  <para style="s1">The Reign of the Lord’s Anointed</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="1" style="v" />Why do the nations rage
and the peoples plot in vain?</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="2" style="v" />The kings of the earth set themselves,
and the rulers take counsel together,
against the Lord and against his Anointed, saying,</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="3" style="v" />“Let us burst their bonds apart
and cast away their cords from us.”</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="4" style="v" />He who sits in the heavens laughs;
the Lord holds them in derision.</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="5" style="v" />Then he will speak to them in his wrath,
and terrify them in his fury, saying,</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="6" style="v" />“As for me, I have set my King
on Zion, my holy hill.”</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="7" style="v" />I will tell of the decree:
The Lord said to me, “You are my Son;
today I have begotten you.</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="8" style="v" />Ask of me, and I will make the nations your heritage,
and the ends of the earth your possession.</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="9" style="v" />You shall break them with a rod of iron
and dash them in pieces like a potter’s vessel.”</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="10" style="v" />Now therefore, O kings, be wise;
be warned, O rulers of the earth.</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="11" style="v" />Serve the Lord with fear,
and rejoice with trembling.</para>
  <para style="p">
    <verse number="12" style="v" />Kiss the Son,
lest he be angry, and you perish in the way,
for his wrath is quickly kindled.
Blessed are all who take refuge in him.</para>
</usx>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_)

chap_old_new = '{"PSA":{"1":"X", "2":"Y"}}'
p_data = json.loads(chap_old_new)

for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag == "book":
        book = elem.text
        book_c = elem.get('code')

    if elem.tag == "chapter":
        #chap = elem.text
        chap_no = elem.get('number')
        # set chapter number value
        try:
            if p_data[book_c]:
                new_no = str(*[v for k, v in p_data[book_c].items() if k == chap_no])
                elem.set('number', new_no)
        except KeyError:
            print("book code and chapter doesn't match. No CHANGE!")
        
    if elem.tag == "verse":
        verse = elem.text
        verse_no = elem.get('number')

ET.dump(root)

